# Assign dynamic key to a predefined struct Golang

Tags: go

I have a struct defined in my project with key value pair as

```
type ObjectInterface struct {
    Vegetables int `json:"vegetable"`
    Fruits     int `json:"fruits"`
    Nuts       int `json:"nuts"`
}
```

Now i have got a payload to be assigned in this struct variable as per whatever key is i get from payload

```
fetchObject := ObjectInterface{
                 [dynamicKey]: 'value'
                }
```

How do i achieve this in golang

Comment: Use a map to unmarshal into, then populate the struct from the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map, map[key]type structure

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by unmarshalling your payloads into `map[string]interface{}{}`.
For Example:

```
var fetchObject map[string]interface{}{}

json.unmarshall(ObjectInterface, &fetchObject)
```

The objectInterface is the payload that  you get.